# which ports to open to to allow communication between two servers

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I'am a novice at this, so please pardon my ignorance

while setting up a new server, which ports need to be opened in order to

- HTTP
- HTTPs
- Moving/copy files between servers using Xcopy
- RDP
- Web Services

Also, do any specific port be opened on the target server in order to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTTP = 80 
HTTPs = 443
XCopy is not a netowrk service
RDP = 3389
Web Services = 80
```

You need to open these ports only on the server side, not on the client.